# File upload in angularjs and laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I am using ngf-file-upload module to upload file through angularjs and laravel.

This is my html initiatior :

```
<div class="button" ngf-select="profile.uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)">Upload on file select</div>
```

This is my controller in angular

```
      vm.uploadFiles = function(file) {
            if (file) {
                file.upload = Upload.upload({
                    url: 'http://localhost/api/uploadImg',
                    data: {file: file}
                });
            }
      }
```

This is my upload API code in Laravel.

```
public function uploadImg()
{
    $data = Input::file('file');
    return $data;
}
```

My angular app is running on 9000 port and laravel in default port.
The request from angular is hitting the api built in laravel but the thing is that it's missing the file. Although my request header looks suspicious in Browser's Network. Like **content-type** is not **multipart/form-data**

[This is the link of danial farid js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/0mz6ff9o/135/)

I am using the same code, with alterations to sync with my api, that is mentioned in the fiddle.

The strange is thing that when i am giving my **local API** path to this fiddle then it is working fine. But it's not working on my project locally. I think there is something that i am missing on my angular side.

[This is the image of param that is send when i am trying to upload file from local project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ2ph.png)

[This is the image of param that is send when i am trying to upload file from fiddle to my api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7y3g.png)

**My Conclusion**

There is no problem in the code because I am able to upload the file from a html file( not in my angular project) that is specifically i have created to test file uploading and it's running.

**BUT**

It's failing when i am trying to upload through my project.
I have attached the **images of my console one case is working one**(uploading image through random file) and other is **not working case** (where i am **uploading file through my project**).

I don't what to do next. I think there is something in my angular project that is creating a obstacle in my uploading process.

Comment: change print_r to `return $data` and check your console to see. The network tab. see what is returned

Comment: It's showing me the same thing. that's nothing. Although the request is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "the request is fine". If you can access the request, then use the request to get the file like `$request->file('file');`

Comment: i have already used that . request is fine fine means i am able to request from angular to laravel but the file is missing.

Comment: Go to network tab in the console, then to 'Headers' and scroll to bottom of it and check Query string paramters. It will show you if you actually send the file or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137030/discussion-between-dherya-and-eddythedove).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Interceptors**

Yes, they were creating problem in file upload because we have set headers in interceptors

and the default headers we have set in interceptors

```
  config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

For every request that has been made from our angular app is going through the interceptor and the interceptor was modifying every request with these headers. So i Have to remove this header from the interceptor.

**Note**

> Don't forget to add the removed header in every other request